# DWORD in windows registry

Tags: registry, dword

I have an application that use registry values for the prices of some items.
It uses the `DWORD` registry value to denote them. Ex:-

```
3f800000 (Hex) value for denote 1.00 
41000000 (Hex) value for denote 4.00
```

So, I am wondering how to convert a value like 1.00 to `DWORD` HEX value.
I need to put 25.00 instead of 1.00. But I'm not sure how to convert the value 25.00 to `DWORD`.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Not sure what is the problem, use [RegistryKey.SetValue Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k23f0345%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to set and use [RegistryKey.GetValue Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdf576x1(v=vs.110).aspx) to retrieve.

Comment: This application is abusing the registry. It is storing a 32-bit IEEE floating point number as if it were a DWORD. You can [use this Web page](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/32bit.html) to convert between them.

Comment: Thank you  "Raymond Chen". It worked for me.thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Run the windows Calculator, then choose the "View" menu and select "Programmer" (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>). Now, you can translate numbers between hexadecimal ("Hex"), decimal ("Dec"), octal ("Oct"), and binary ("Bin") by clicking the respective radio button. You can also switch between 8-bit mode (`Byte`), 16-bit (`Word`), 32-bit (`Dword`), and 64-bit (`Qword`).